# nginxのfastcgi_buffersの設定値の意味を教えてください

Tags: nginx

nginx と php-fpm 環境にて「upstream sent too big header」というエラーがでたのですが、調べてみると以下の2つのパラメータを調整するとよいという情報がでてきました。

- fastcgi_buffers
- fastcgi_buffer_size

そこで、これらを以下のように設定する正しく画面が表示できるようになりました。

```
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k
fastcgi_buffer_size 16k
```

しかし、ドキュメントを見ても fastcgi_buffers の **8** の(下記のnumberの部分)がどういう意味なのかわからず、妥当な設定値がわかりません。

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_buffers

この設定値はどのような意味を持つのか教えてください。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[こちら](http://server-setting.info/centos/nginx-fastcgi-cache.html)のサイトに説明が記載してありました。

> FastCGIの応答のバッファサイズ(4k or 8k)とその個数を設定します。デフォルトは、個数は 8
>   個で、バッファサイズはシステムに依存します。

Comment: リンク先も含めて理解できました!ありがとうございました。